# When trying to convert Keras .h5 file to .tflite file: Converter gives AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'call'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, converters, tensorflow-lite

The line "tflite_model = converter.convert()" gives the AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'call'.

See screenshot of code ->[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKyOJ.png)

CODE:

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model('///Users/theunskuhn/Desktop/Savedfile/basic_malaria_pos_neg_v3.h5')
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("basic_malaria_pos_neg_v3.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

ERROR:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'call'

The Error points to the line 4: "tflite_model = converter.convert()"

[Screenshot of new code from answer below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcLhd.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `TFLiteConverter` API in TensorFlow 2.0 or above, the `TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model` takes in a Keras `Model` object and not the path of the model which is `str`.

First, load the model using `tf.keras.models.load_model()` and then pass this model to the `TFLiteConverter` API.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model( '///Users/theunskuhn/Desktop/Savedfile/basic_malaria_pos_neg_v3.h5' )

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model( model )
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("basic_malaria_pos_neg_v3.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

The method `TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file()` was replaced by `TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model()` in TF 2.0. See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/index#convert_a_keras_model_).

Comment: I tried this but ```TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file()``` expects a .pbtxt or .pb file instead of a .h5 file: {saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Comment: Did you try the code above? Does the above code give this message?

Comment: Yes I tried the above code and that was the message. I will add a screenshot to the original question.

Comment: Seems like your path is incorrect. Try this: `import os `, `my_model_path = os.path.join(os.path.sep, "Users", "theunskuhn", "Desktop", "SavedFile", "basic_malaria_pos_neg_v3.h5")` ant then load your model with `model = tf.keras.models.load_model(my_model_path)` and double check the path exists.